# How to use pages property of Navigator in flutter correctly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am following this Navigator 2.0 article : https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade
and I am able to run it and trying to understand various parts of it by making simple modifications.

I am having trouble understanding the role of the "pages" parameter that is being passed while building the navigator. My understanding is that pages is a list of pages that represent the stack of screens and the top most screen on that stack is what is displayed to the user. Further, when the user presses the back button, the top most screen is removed (popped) and the one below it becomes active. Is this correct understanding?

To test my understanding, I modified the build method of BookRouterDelegate as follows (I just added a RandomScreen1 to the pages list at the beginning):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Navigator(
    key: navigatorKey,
    pages: [

//------------ ADDED THE FOLLOWING -----
      MaterialPage(
        key: ValueKey('RandomScreen1Page'),
        child: RandomScreen1(
        ),
      ),
//----- END ADDITION----------

      MaterialPage(
        key: ValueKey('BooksListPage'),
        child: BooksListScreen(
          books: books,
          onTapped: _handleBookTapped,
        ),
      ),
      if (show404)
        MaterialPage(key: ValueKey('UnknownPage'), child: UnknownScreen())
      else if (_selectedBook != null)
        BookDetailsPage(book: _selectedBook!)
    ],
    onPopPage: (route, result) {
      print("onpoproute ${route} ${result} ");
      if (!route.didPop(result)) {
        print("route did not pop");
        return false;
      }

      // Update the list of pages by setting _selectedBook to null
      _selectedBook = null;
      show404 = false;
      notifyListeners();

      return true;
    },
  );
}
```

I was expecting that when the user is on book list screen and presses the back button, the RandomScreen will be displayed. But that is not what is happening. What happens is the RandomScreen is displayed for a fraction of a second, and then the BookList screen is shown.

I don't understand why. Is the pages list supposed to have exactly one page?